# Ruby sql to trim an entire column in a model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a location model with an attribute name.
I want to trim(remove extra white spaces) the entire name attribute.

I tried to run

```
Location.TRIM(name)
```

But it isnt working. is the query wrong?

Comment: what is  `trim` means?

Comment: to remove extra white spaces before after and in between

Comment: Why has this been marked as a duplicate of a question about stripping using Ruby, when this is clearly about the `TRIM` in sql?

Comment: @Ilya yes the question is about sql not string object. Could you remove the duplicate? In this case it update all the already saved Location in database with a sql method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

`Location.update_all('name = TRIM(name)')`

Comment: Thanks .. It worked! :)